# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value [Tilting Issue]

Tags: ios

For some odd reason, this line:

```
    var x = motionManager.accelerometerData.acceleration.x
```

keep throwing an error like this:

```
    fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional   value
```

this is the rest of the code around it:

```
     var motionManager = CMMotionManager()

     if motionManager.accelerometerAvailable == true {
        motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates()
        var x = motionManager.accelerometerData.acceleration.x
        NSLog("X: %i",x)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It takes some small amount of time before the hardware reports any accelerometer data, so I believe that's why you get that error. You might want to use `startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:withHandler` instead, and deal with the received data inside the handler.

Comment: How would I implement this into my code? Ive never used Accelerometer.

Answer (score 0):

`var x = motionManager.accelerometerData.acceleration.x` is throwing an error because `motionManager.accelerometerData` is an optional and it can be nil. Check for the value and unwrap it if it exists, otherwise do not try and unwrap the optional when its nil.